# 80's sci fi movie where a man or android drives underground across America

Tags: story-identification, movie

What is the name of an 80's sci fi movie where a man either thinks he is an android or may not know he is, and he either drives across America in the underground parking/tunnels to either save a woman or is perhaps driving her to the destination.

Answer (score 5):

It could be *Circuitry Man* (1990)--as mentioned in the review [here](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1990-10-31-ca-3233-story.html) it's set in a future where all cities have been relocated underground due to aboveground pollution, and the story involves a female bodyguard traveling with a "bio-synthetic" gigolo to deliver some illegal microchips from Los Angeles to New York. Though the review mentions that much of the cross-country trip takes place in the aboveground wastelands rather than the underground setting of the city scenes.